# How can I detect create , update, delete data in stream in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to detect insert, delete and update events happen in StreamBuilder in flutter.

```
StreamBuilder<List<Map<String,dynamic>>>(
      stream: _myStream,
      builder: (context,snapshot){
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount:snapshot.data!.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext, index){
            return StatefulWidget();
          },
        );
      },
    );
```

In this `ListView.builder` all events working fine, but I cant detect which event was fire , So How can I detect these events ?

Comment: if u use firebase, it automatically detects

Comment: No, I am not using firebase.